# How to convert a column of text into n-grams into one-hot encoding?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nltk, one-hot-encoding, n-gram

I have this dataframe:

| ID | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | this is text |
| 2 | here is text |

I'd like to convert it to a dataframe that looks like this using python:

| ID | this | is | here | text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

I've looked at nltk, but can't seem to find a straight forward solution, I'm sure people have done this before and I can brute-force it, but my actual dataframe is quite large. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, your example doesn't actually use n-grams (except, if you want to think about the trivial case, unigrams). It's also not a one-hot encoding. Both rows you show are multi-hot. Do you want to make what you showed, or to make what you said?

Comment: 1) i'm thinking about the trivial case, eventually i'll need to do bi- and trigrams

2) I want to make what I'm showing

Comment: Higher-order n-grams are a separate question.

Comment: As far as making the incidence matrix you showed—the popular way is [scikit-learn's CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html).

Comment: Not really. unigrams, bigrams, and trigrams can be obtained easily using R's quanteda package. However with python, I'm having trouble doing something similar.

Comment: Yeah, there are packages that provide similar functionality in Python. But you need to keep your question focused. (See [ask].)